# File browser error - IMCE

Tags: files

IMCE - http://ufku.com/drupal/imce/7

I am trying to load file browser window via IMCE module on CHOOSE FILE button-(form upload field) click.

My following code loads such window fine from which I can select a file. But once I select the file, it opens a new window and display image file in new window instead of adding that file name in CHOOSE FILE button for me to further save and upload that file to my location (same as normal form file upload does).

Please note that I am not using IMCE in WYSIWYG editor rather a form upload field.

Here is my code;

$form['image_file'] = array(
  '#type' => 'file',
  '#title' => t('File *'),
  '#size' => 20,
  '#description' => t('Please use JPG file only.'),
  '#upload_validators' => array(
    'file_validate_extensions' => array('pdf'),
  ),
  '#upload_location' => 'public://my_image_files/',
  '#attributes' => array('onclick' => "window.open('/imce', '', 'width=760,height=560,resizable=1')"),
);

By following the documentation in http://ufku.com/drupal/imce/7, I have tried using

'/imce?app=myApp|sendto@myFileHandler'

and have created this function to call but no luck.

(function myFileHandler(file, win) {
  alert('FILE UPLOAD myOnloadFunc');
  $('#urlFieldId').val(file.url);//insert file url into the url field
  win.close();//close IMCE
})(window.jQuery, window.Drupal, window.Drupal.bootstrap);

Any idea what I am doing wrong here or perhaps I am missing configuration settings somewhere?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved this with the following;

1)

```
<script>   
function imageFileSelector() {  window.open('/imce?urlField=edit-image-file-path-1', '', 'width=760,height=560,resizable=1');   } 
</script>
```

'edit-image-file-path-1' is id value for form field 'image_file_path_1'.

2)

```
$form['image_file_selector'] = array(
  '#markup' => t("<br /><b>Image File *</b><br><a onclick=imageFileSelector();>Click to choose Image File</a><br>"),
);
$form['image_file_path_1'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#attributes' => array('readonly' => 'readonly'),
  '#default_value' => $result->image_file_path_1,
);
```